# how to enable offline mode for split and shared database

Tags: backend, offline, ms-access-2016

Good morning everyone.
I am fairly new to working with microsoft access and only used it during my internship so far.
my task is to develop a tool that will help to electronically collect data from some of our operating machines. so basically what is happening is this. in the future the operator will no longer fill out a paper sheet in order to track the Manufacturing process but will just enterthe data into the created access form which will then be uploaded to an excel sheet that is saved on sharepoint.
now here is my Problem. It might happen that due to some problems the interent connection on our shopfloor will break down. i have come to notice that when this happens so access and sharepoint get disconnected i wount be able to keep working with my application.
my question is this now. is it possible to add some sort of offline working mode?
I thought about kind of having a local back end that will for one first step save the data locally then on a timer based event checks if there is a stable wifi connection and copys the data into my linked sharepoint table. but i dont exacly know how this would work.
if you have any experience regarding this problem some hints would be most apppreciated for i kind of dont know hoe to pursuit from this point on
kind Regards
Fjell

i tried to build a mechanism that would check whether i am connected or not but trying add a record into a Shared "Test" database and set a error flag to true when an error occurs. if we are connected so error flag = false then we would try to upload the data into the shared table.
the problem is i dont get it to work fast enough to reliably detect if we are online or not